# how do sort items in a text file within its contained time interval

Tags: linux, bash, sorting, grep

I'm writing a bash script that sorts a list on text file, based on a preset time interval on the entry, in this case I have a text file named `final.txt` , which contains these lines:

```
14-Oct-2013|04:18|
14-Oct-2013|04:16|
14-Oct-2013|04:20|
14-Oct-2013|05:16|
14-Oct-2013|06:16|
```

and I'm going to display entries on a text file which is from 04:16 to 05:16, sequentially, chronologically. So it will display like this:

```
14-Oct-2013|04:18|
14-Oct-2013|04:16|
14-Oct-2013|04:20|
14-Oct-2013|05:16|
```

and the result shouldn't display the last line, since the last line is out of the set time interval (04:16 to 05:16)

and i tried grep for the start time interval, but i don't know what to do to sort entries within the start and the end time interval. i'd like to pipe it to grep again to sort for the end interval time, but, i know, that will display nothing

anyway, here is my code:

```
cat final.txt | grep $DATE_TO_SORT | sort | grep $HOUR_TO_SORT | sort
```

does anyone here have a solution? it will be appreciated

Comment: What is meant by "latter line" ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since `perl` is available in any unix flavor, and you can use it from command line, I would use it in this way:

```
$ perl -n -e 'print "$_" if (/(.+)\|(.+)\|/ && $1 eq "14-Oct-2013" && $2 >= "04:18" && $2 <= "05:16")' | sort
14-Oct-2013|04:16|
14-Oct-2013|04:18|
14-Oct-2013|04:20|
14-Oct-2013|05:16|
```

This could be simplest:

```
$ perl -n -e 'print $_ if ($_ ge "14-Oct-2013|04:16" && $_ lt "14-Oct-2013|05:17")' | sort
14-Oct-2013|04:16|
14-Oct-2013|04:18|
14-Oct-2013|04:20|
14-Oct-2013|05:16|
```

To read sh vars you just hast to use correctly quotes and $, so as the shell can expand variables, here you have two cases using single or double quotes to embrace perl arguments:

```
$ FROM="14-Oct-2013|04:16"
$ TO="14-Oct-2013|05:17"
$ perl -n -e 'print $_ if ($_ ge "'$FROM'" && $_ lt "'$TO'")' | sort
or
$ perl -n -e "print \$_ if (\$_ ge '$FROM' && \$_ lt '$TO')" | sort
```

Comment: `from 04:16 to 05:16`

Comment: `set time interval (04:16 to 05:16)`

Comment: anyway, how do i use my bash variables to perl? it seems perl didn't read the bash variables

Answer (score -1):

Use -k option of sort to sort by column.
I used `tr` to translate your data to column data.

```
user@m:/tmp$ cat final.txt | tr "|" "\t" | sort -k 2
14-Oct-2013 04:16   
14-Oct-2013 04:18   
14-Oct-2013 04:20   
14-Oct-2013 05:16   
14-Oct-2013 06:16
```

Comment: All this does is remove the `|` and sorts which can be achieve with a single command `sort -t'|' -k2  file`.

Answer (score -1):

This will do what you require and is useful for any date / time range

```
#!/bin/bash

fn=test.txt
sn=${fn}.sorted

# date to search for
dn=14-Oct-2013
# start time
st=04:16
# end time
et=05:16

# get the output in date/time order
sort -V $fn >$sn
# find the first line number that is of interest (date / time)
startline=`grep $dn $sn |grep -n $st|head -n 1|cut -d: -f1`
# adjust to make results inclusive, comment this to make exclusive
startline=$(( startline - 1 ))
# find the last line number of interest
endline=`grep $dn $sn |grep -n $et |tail -n 1|cut -d: -f1`
# get the total number of lines
numlines=`wc -l $sn|cut -d" " -f 1`
# compute the number of lines to display
displines=$(( endline - startline ))
# compute the window size to search within
windowstart=$(( numlines - startline ))
# display the relevent lines from $startline to $endline
tail -n $windowstart $sn |head -n $displines
```